# Conditional field in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes

I want to insert a field in the footer that will display the text "hello" if the page number is lesser than or equal to 2, and "bye" otherwise. How to do it?

I have tried `IF {PAGE}<=2 "hello" "bye"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, copy the code you already have

Then within the footer press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>. This will insert the outer `{}` . This is different compared to you typing them!

You should see 2 braces. Now paste the content between them.

> { if { PAGE } <= 2 "Hello" "Bye" }

<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> will toggle conditional formatting (code)

With conditional formatting shown you can see the code (screen shot):

[image]